# Internal polar system of my creature

Tags: xenobiology, biochemistry, bio-mechanics

My fauna has a mysterious internal polar system, which enables him to create an aura of voluminous clouds of absolute zero temperatures and summon torrential ice blizzards. What material is my creature made of that withstand this much cold? What compounds is my creature mixed in its body to create all these effects?

Comment: "absolute zero temperatures" is that [Absolute Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_zero) or some strange effect by which the area has no temperature at all? I ask because the phrase doesn't quite make sense as it is currently written.

Answer (score 4):

First things first, neither creating clouds or getting anything to absolute zero is feasibly possible for any old creature to do without crazy magic powers. Even we are unable to reach absolute zero with our current technology and we can only manipulate the weather to a certain degree. However let’s say your creature, using magic, could create clouds of absolute zero.

First of all, if a cloud suddenly became absolute zero then it isn’t a cloud anymore. Clouds are just a bunch of water droplets floating in the atmosphere, when they condense together and grow enough they become to heavy and fall to the ground. This is commonly referred to as rain. If the cloud is in freezing temperature then the droplets freeze and become snow. Things are hot or cold because of the energy within their particles. Things freeze when there is so little energy in the particles that they can’t escape the other particles’ force of attraction. Usually it still has some energy but not enough to break the force of attraction of its fellow particles. Absolute zero means that the particles have zero energy, literally motionless particles. There is a theoretical new state of matter for particles which are this cold. However what’s more scary is what happens around these ‘clouds’.

Matter has the tendency to get more dense (smaller with the same mass) when it gets cold and less dense when it warms up. Matter tends to also like to balance out temperature, exchanging heat between matter until they are balanced out. The larger the difference in temperature, the quicker this exchange happens. So now picture this, the creature summons super dense absolute zero water in the sky, surrounded by room temperature air. These ‘clouds’ wouldn’t create blizzards, they would violently explode. As the clouds suck out heat from the surrounding air, the air contracts which sucks in more air while they grow rapidly within fractions of a second. This would happen so fast that they would literally pop. The scale of the explosion would depend on how much ‘cloud’ the creature created but a standard array of clouds would be fairly powerful. There would probably be all sorts of other side affects and untended disastrous consequences but it definitely wouldn’t create some snow storms.
Also, to answer your question, there is nothing this creature could do or be made out of to survive the extreme temperature of absolute zero. Everything freezes at these temperatures, becoming its own theoretical state of matter.

In conclusion, if this creature for some magical reason, has the ability to summon absolute zero ’clouds’, then everyone dies. Maybe just stick with the more mundane magic power to just summon regular clouds and go from there.

Comment: *"Clouds are just a bunch of water vapor floating in the atmosphere:"* Nope. Clouds are made of tiny little droplets of *liquid* water. (Quick check: water vapor is a colorless transparent gas. Clouds are not transparent. Which means that they cannot be made of water vapor.)

Comment: My mistake, I knew clouds were made of tiny water droplets, I just mixed them up. They still would explode though

Comment: I think it would technically be an implosion, as the gas in the clouds no longer has the kinetic energy to generate outward pressure and the air around it collapses into the cold pocket. It might create a giant packed ice ball at the center...